# Show Block only if it's a front page and GET variable is set

Tags: blocks

I am setting up a block in Drupal 7 to "show block on specific pages" through PHP.

What I want is that if it's a Front page and there is a GET (`listed`) variable, only then it shows the block otherwise not.

Hence, the block would only be shown, if the url is `www.site.com/?listed=true`

I tried this, but it doesn't work:-

```
<?php
if ( (drupal_is_front_page()) && ( !empty($_GET['listed'])  ) {
  return true;
}
?>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing bracket. Try this:

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page() && !empty($_GET['listed'])) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page() && isset($_GET['listed'])) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module. It gives you lot of options to configure.

In your case you can add a new context and put two conditions

1. Path = `<front>`
2. Query String : `listed=true`

then add a reaction to display the block you want. Its simple.